# Measure Theory - Modes of convergence of $f_n(x) = (1/x)(\sin(x))^n$

Tags: measure-theory

**Question:** Consider the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{x}(\sin(x))^n$ on $(0, \infty)$, equipped with the Borel σ−algebra and Lebesgue measure $λ$. Does it hold that $f_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for each of the following types of convergence:

a) pointwise?
b) pointwise a.e?
c) in measure?
d) in $L^p$ for $1 < p < \infty$?
e) in $L^\infty$?

**My attempt:**

a) is False since for for example the x for which $\sin(x)=1$, then $f_n$ does not converge to $0$.

b) is True because the reason a) was False is that it fails to converge on only a set of measure $0$ since it was countable.

I'm struggling with c), d), and e). My thought on c) was to use that $\sin(x)/x$ is bounded by $x$, and then it would mean that $\sin(x)^{n-1}$ would go to zero a.e. so it converges in measure, but I don't know if that is correct to think like that. On d) and e) I have no idea.

Any suggestions for how to solve c),d), and e)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\mu \{x: |f_n(x)| >\epsilon\}$. Note that  $|f_n(x)| >\epsilon$ implies $\frac 1  {|x|} >\epsilon$. So  $\mu \{x: |f_n(x)| >\epsilon\} \leq \mu \{|x|\leq \frac 1 {\epsilon}: f_n(x) >\epsilon\}$. On a set of finite measure a.e. convergence implies convergence in measure so $\mu \{|x|\leq \frac 1 {\epsilon}: |f_n(x)| >\epsilon\} \to 0$ proving that $(f_n)$ does converge in measure to $0$.

It is is easy to see that $(f_n)$ does not converge in $L^{\infty}$: If it does then $|f_n(x)|<\epsilon$ a.e. as soon as $n$ exceeds some $m$. By continuity we must have $|f_{m+1}(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$. But there exists a  point $x \in (0,\frac   1 {\epsilon})$ with $\sin x =1$ provided $\epsilon <\frac 2 {\pi}$. But then $|f_{m+1}(x)|=\frac 1 x >\epsilon$, a contradiction

$(f_n)$ does converge in $L^{p}$ to $0$ for $1<p<\infty$. This is an easy consequence of DCT since $|f_n(x)|^{p} \leq \frac 1 {|x|^{p}}$ for $|x|>1$. [For $|x|<1$, $|f_n(x)| \leq \frac {|\sin x|} {|x|}\leq 1$].

Comment: Thanks. Two questions. First, for convergence in measure you said "On a set of finite measure a.e. convergence implies convergence in measure", but here the set is not of finite measure since it is $(0,\infty)$, or did you mean that the set $\lvert x \rvert \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}: f_n(x) > \epsilon$ is of finite measure? Second, on $L^{\infty}$. I don't understand "If it does then $\lvert f_n(x) \rvert < \epsilon$ a.e. as soon as  exceeds some . By continuity we must have $\lvert f_{m+1}(x) \rvert < \epsilon$ for all x." Can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: @user: Alternatively, d) implies c).

Comment: $\{x: |x| \leq \frac 1 {\epsilon }\}$ is obviously a set of finite Lebesgue measure.  If $f$ is continuous and $|f(x)| \leq C$ a.e then $|f(x)| \leq C$ for all $x$. This follows from the fact that if a set has measure $0$ then its complement is dense. @user5744148